# How to solve header issue in AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

The data is working fine in Postman app but not working in code. Below is the code

```
  NSString* link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://apifm.azurewebsites.net/token"];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager* manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:nil];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


[manager POST:link parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    NSMutableData *email = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSMutableData *password = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSMutableData *grantType = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [email appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"testman1@foodmandu.com"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [password appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"testUserPw"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [grantType appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"password"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [formData appendPartWithFormData:email name:@"UserName"];
    [formData appendPartWithFormData:password name:@"Password"];
    [formData appendPartWithFormData:grantType name:@"grant_type"];

} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, id responseObject) {





    NSLog(@"success");

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSError* error){


    [API alertViewWithMessage:[[operation responseObject] objectForKey:@"error"] inController:self];
}];
```

Below are the screenshots of Postman app 
[image: Header]

[image: Body]

The error which i get when executing code is given below

> error Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0x7faf3b6d6cf0 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: http://apifm.azurewebsites.net/token } { status code: 400, headers {
>       "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
>       "Content-Length" = 34;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
>       Date = "Sun, 05 Jul 2015 07:11:19 GMT";
>       Expires = "-1";
>       Pragma = "no-cache";
>       Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
>       "Set-Cookie" = "ARRAffinity=ebb02fb6b319b5ae83e167620f3bc3ad6e68d31fb30aff79ef123aabd981588e;Path=/;Domain=apifm.azurewebsites.net";
>       "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
>   } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://apifm.azurewebsites.net/token, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b226572 726f7222 3a22756e 73757070 6f727465 645f6772 616e745f 74797065 227d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}

To remind you, the data is working fine in Postman.

Comment: I have checked this on postman and i am getting response as "unsupported_grant_type", Can you confirm fi your full post url looks like this https://apifm.azurewebsites.net/token?UserName=testman1@foodmandu.com&Password=testUserPw&grant_type=password

Comment: @Max Yeah, i just confirmed. Also, you can see in error log which is in last of my question there is http://apifm.azurewebsites.net/token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the parameters as NSDictionary, like " NSDictionary *parameters =  @{@"UserName": @"testman1@foodmandu.com", @"Password": @"testUserPw", @"grant_type": @"password"}; "

This can be achieved using the following code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters =  @{@"UserName": @"testman1@foodmandu.com", @"Password": @"testUserPw", @"grant_type": @"password"};
[manager POST:@"http://apifm.azurewebsites.net/token" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Please try the above and let me know your feedback.